# Правильно ли используются принципы ООП

Tags: c#, ооп

Имеется абстрактный класс Фигура c абстрактными методами. Его наследует абстрактный класс Фигура2D, которая определяет методы родителя.
К классу Фигура2D добавлены также виртуальные методы.

Вопросы: 
1) Нормально ли, что в абстрактном классе Фигура2D имеются методы с телом (методы родителя, которые нужно реализовать) 
2) Нормально ли, что абстрактный класс имеет **виртуальные** методы (то есть класс является одновременно полиморфным и абстрактным)

p.s.: Реализуется в c#

Comment: Ну да, если того действительно требует задача, а не использование ООП ради ООП

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Да. Хотя лично я не припомню, чтобы видел иерархию наследования с
   двумя абстрактными классами. Вообще, чем дальше практикуешь ООП, тем
   больше предпочитаешь простые иерархии и композицию.
2. Да. Абстрактный класс тем и отличается от интерфейса, что
   может содержать некоторое поведение по умолчанию, которое как раз и
   может содержаться в виртуальных методах.

Answer (score 4):

> 1) Нормально ли, что в абстрактном классе Фигура2D имеются методы с телом (методы родителя, которые нужно реализовать)

Главное отличие интерфейса от абстрактного класса в том, что абстрактный класс может содержать не только объявление операции, но содержать и реализацию.

При этом абстрактный класс может содержать не только виртуальные методы (объявление + реализация по умолчанию), но также может содержать и невиртуальные методы, которые определяют основу некоторого алгоритма, стабильного для всех подклассов, но с некоторым переменным шагом, который определяется конкретным наследником.

За этим замысловатым описанием скрывается один из самых распространенных паттернов проектирования, под названием [Шаблонный метод](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2014/03/template-method-design-pattern.html), который является фундаментальным для создания удобных в использовании иерархий типов.

Выглядит он может так:

```
abstract class Shape {}

abstract class Shape2D : Shape
{
  public void Draw()
  {
     DrawFirstPart();
     DrawSecondPart();
     FillShape();
  }

  protected abstract DrawFirstPart();
  protected abstract DrawSecondPart();
  protected abstract FillShap();
}
```

> 2) Нормально ли, что абстрактный класс имеет виртуальные методы (то есть класс является одновременно полиморфным и абстрактным).

Наличие конкретных методов в абстракном классе не делает его "конкретным" или "полиморфным". Любой абстрактный класс будет содержать реализацию, в противном случае вы бы использовали интерфейс.

Comment: Нуууу... Всё же отличие интерфейса от абстрактного класса больше, чем наличие реализованных методов. Семантически интерфейс есть контракт, а абстрактный класс — средство повторного использования кода.

Comment: @VladD  _"Семантически интерфейс есть контракт"_  -- интересно, вот есть сигнатура метода - это понятно, но если одну или несколько сигнатур группируют в именованный блок, то называют это контракт. почему? мне кажется, что контракт - это именно интерфейс + реализация.

Comment: @Stack: Контракт в том смысле, что если мне в метод пришёл объект, реализующий интерфейс, я могу быть уверенным, что у этого объекта есть методы с данными сигнатурами, и что их можно безопасно вызывать.

Comment: @VladD _"если мне в метод пришёл объект, реализующий интерфейс"_ -- это понятно, в рантайме у вас есть интерфейс + реализация в объекте -- это и есть контракт. а интерфейс без реализации - это группа методов с определенными сигнатурами.

Comment: @Stack: Не, реализация не является частью контракта-интерфейса. Обычно вы как архитектор не хотите налагать настолько жёсткие требования: «я ожидаю здесь метод X и его конкретную реализацию», вы хотите лишь «я ожидаю здесь метод X».

Comment: @VladD _" вы хотите лишь «я ожидаю здесь метод X»"_ -- да, и ожидаю определенное поведение/реакцию, но как это будет сделано, т.е. конкретная реализация не имеет значения.

Comment: @Stack: Ну, тогда вам нужен именно интерфейс, правильно?

Comment: @Stack: То есть, в этом случае вам нужен чистый интерфейс. Ну по идее это и называется «контракт» — то, что объекты, приходящие к вам, обязуются уметь делать.

Comment: @VladD мы в принципе об одном говорим, но есть одна деталь: контракт - это интерфейс в рантайме. контракт без объекта  - это просто интерфейс. так же как в жизни - контракт без исполнителя - это просто текст на бумаге, пустое обещание. согласны?

Comment: @Stack: Ну, как бы да, разногшласий я не вижу, но я не вполне понимаю, к чему вы клоните. Если ко мне в метод пришёл объект, то он обязан реализовать интерфейс, так что контракт с исполнителем. Если ко мне в метод не пришёл никакой объект, метод не вызвался, то контракт без исполнителя, но в этом вроде бы проблемы нету.

Comment: @VladD _"я не вполне понимаю, к чему вы клоните."_  -- к тому, что интерфейс - это (в коде) - "сигнатура", а контракт - это (в рантайме) - интерфейс + объект.

Comment: @Stack: Не совсем понимаю, в чём отличие. Контракт — штука периода компиляции, на мой вкус. (Или может быть вы оперируете каким-то конкретным смыслом слова «контракт»?)

Comment: @VladD _"Контракт — штука периода компиляции"_ -- понятно. но раньше вы сказали _" Семантически интерфейс есть контракт, а абстрактный класс — средство повторного использования кода"_ -- т.к. абстрактные классы не копилируются, т.е. значит вы говорили не о периоде компиляции. получается путаница, или просто я неправильно понимаю.

Comment: @Stack: Хм, почему абстрактные классы не компилируются? Я говорю по сути лишь о периоде компиляции.

Comment: @VladD _"почему абстрактные классы не компилируются?"_ -- попробуйте `var a = new A(); abstract class A { abstract public void run(); }` получите `error CS0144: Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface`

Comment: @Stack: Ну, объект не создаётся, но почему `A` при этом не компилируется? Вроде бы вполне себе компилируется.

Comment: @VladD _"Ну, объект не создаётся, но почему A при этом не компилируется?"_ -- объект создается в рантайме. а во время компиляции не создаются объекты программы. есть только код и ошибка компиляции будет на строке `var a = new A();`.

Comment: @Stack: Это понятно, но почему вы говорите, что _код класса_ `A` не компилируется (если я правильно вас понял)?

Comment: @VladD _"почему вы говорите, что код класса A не компилируется"_ --   я [сказал](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413684/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%8b-%d0%9e%d0%9e%d0%9f/414737?noredirect=1#comment542638_414737) "абстрактные классы не копилируются", потому что в коментариях мало места, хотя надо было сказать "код программ в которых используются (создаются и т.д.) абстрактные классы не компилируется".

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33333/discussion-between-vladd-and-stack).